# How to add a common feature over different branches

Tags: git, git-flow

I have two branches say b1, b2. I need to add a feature to both these(b1, b2) branches.
Do I need to do it twice once in b1 and in b2?
what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you have any other branches besides `b1` and `b2`?

Comment: yeah, there are other branches too.

Comment: I was going to suggest making the change in the source branch, if all branches would need it, then rebase your feature branches on that source branch.

Comment: yeah that seems to be good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both branches would require this feature, it would have made sense if their mutual source branch actually already had this feature in it.  So, one option here would be to make the change in their parent branch, then rebase the two branches on the parent (or maybe merge the parent into the two branches `b1` and `b2`).

Comment: Feature wasn't there in the parent branch, it's a new feature which needs to be done in b1 & b2(Here b1&b2 implies different versions of a product).

Comment: My answer assumes that at some point you would be merging the branches back anyway.  If it won't work, then you can make the change on one branch and then cherry pick it to the other one.